# How to save a PDF file in a SQL Server column using Delphi code

Tags: delphi, pdf, sql-server-2008-r2, delphi-6, blobstorage

G'd day, everyone...

Here is the scenario. My user wants to save a PDF file into the database (yeah, I know, that's not the optimal way to do it, but ... he pays, so I keep my mouth shut ;) ), so I decided to create a `Binary` column in a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

And now, the problem. I'm developing in Delphi 6, and I have the slightest idea how to accomplish this..., can you provide me kinda help here, please?

Thanks in advance for your kindness.

Comment: Not being a Delphi guy myself, I'll tread lightly here. But, I would recommend varbinary(max) for the data type, instead of binary. Binary is limited to 8k, but varbinary(max) allows up to 2GB (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)

Comment: There are a lot of well known products that store files inside the DB. `SharePoint` is one of them (although there is a `SharePoint` external storage API also). BTW, "but ... he pays, so I keep my mouth shut" - this kind of approach can backfire at *you* later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stream the PDF into a blob field.  I use this technique for saving .JPG and .PNG images into a DBISAM database. You can probably find examples of doing this for images (stream an image into a blob field).